# Put a variable as an argument of a function

Tags: python, function, arguments, parameter-passing

So I need to use a variable(n) as the default value of another function(parameter).

```
def fit(X_train,Y_train):
   df=pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack((X_train, Y_train)))
   global n
   var=parameters()
   n = df.shape[1] - 1
```

I want to use the value of **'n'** as an argument to the function **'parameter'** given below as a default argument. I have to declare a global variable as n=0, otherwise, it gives an error saying name n is not defined.

```
def parameters(degree = 1, nof = n):
   global d
   d=degree
   f=n
   nof=f
   return nof
```

Now **'f'** has always the value of n from the function fit. Hence whenever I put another value of nof while calling the function parameter **nof** changes itself to the value of **n**.
I want the value of nof to be **'n'** only when the user does not specify any values to **nof**. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Make a module level variable named `'n'` and *define* it before you define the function(s).

Comment: [A Word About Names and Objects, Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-word-about-names-and-objects) ... [Structure of a program, naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#structure-of-a-program)

Answer (score 0):

Default values are set when a function is declared, not when it's run. This can lead to surprising behavior when you modify variables:

```
n = 1

def parameters(nof = n):  # The default argument is n, but...
   return nof

n = 5

print(parameters())  # This prints 1, not 5!
```

Instead of setting the default variable to `n`, it's safer to only apply that default when the function runs, using `None` as a placeholder:

```
def parameters(nof = None):
    if nof is None:
        nof = n  # The 'global' keyword isn't necessary, but you can include it to be explicit

    return nof
```

Alternately, if you only use the `parameters` function inside the `fit` function, you can make it an internal function to avoid dealing with global variables. This internal function will automatically have access to the outer function's scope:

```
def fit():
   n = 0  # Not global scoped

   def parameters(nof = None):
       if nof is None:
           nof = n  # This is the same 'n' defined above
       return nof

   var = parameters()  # This returns 0
   n = 1
   var = parameters()  # This returns 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. The problem is function parameter is always going to be called before function fit where the n gets its value.